# What is electric energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-fields

From what I have learned it appears that while electricity is defined as a movement of charges, electric energy, on the other hand, is a form of electromagnetic waves and it moves through empty space outside of wires and not inside of wires.

If this be the case, what makes electric energy far more powerful than another form of EM waves that move through empty space?  Furthermore, electric energy is a very low-frequency form of EM waves.

My only thought about it is perhaps because electric energy is a near field phenomenon with very little of it being far field.  However, I am not certain if this reasoning is the correct one or if it has any relationship to a near field or far field phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

> what makes electric energy far more powerful than another form of EM waves that move through empty space?

Indeed, as you first assumed, this has to do with far field vs near field. In waves going through empty space the energy is in the far field and tends to spread out. Around a wire the EM energy stays very localized and does not spread very far away from the wire at all.

You can use Poynting’s theorem to calculate the energy density near a wire and determine how close it is and which direction it moves. For a DC power wire the power does not go out at all. In fact it points slightly inwards representing the power lost to Ohmic heating of the wire itself.

Comment: But which aspect of the two the electric or the magnetic part that makes that keeps the energy moving to follow along the wire? Is the magnetic component the stronger of the two-component in this context of what we experience or termed as electric energy, separate and different from other forms of energy?  As there is not much electric field around the wires as much is the magnetic field.  Also, there is what is termed as the reactive component of the energy and that stays within various parts of the system.

Comment: @Ali said “which aspect of the two the electric or the magnetic part that makes that keeps the energy moving to follow along the wire”, the energy flow is the product of the two, so both are equally important. You said “there is not much electric field around the wires as much is the magnetic field”, both are present, but in SI units they are different units so you cannot compare which is larger or smaller.